# real-time update page feed

Tags: facebook-graph-api, real-time

here I am for real update "page", add fields to status to receive the "status" of
pages, I try to add as "link" fields to receive the subscription works but I do
not receive notification when I publish a link, it's really difficult to have
correct information

{
      "object": "user",
      "callback_url": "http://*****/fbcallback.php",
      "fields": [
        "feed",
        "link",
        "status"
      ],
      "active": true
    }

http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=18048#c40

Answer (score -2):

As per the documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/ :

> To setup a subscription, send a **POST** with the following parameters

It seems like you're posting a JSON object while you should do is a normal post with these variables (as if you're doing a  with action="post").

Note, by the way, that the fields parameter needs to have a CSV value, so that would be "feed,link,status", and that there's no 'active' attribute.